# What is the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table; equivalent for jTable1.setValueAt?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, swt

I've moved from using NetBeans to Eclipse.

And as such lines like the below don't work, as I've moved from using:

JTables to SWT Tables

How can I modify this line of code to work for SWT Tables:

```
jTable1.setValueAt(v.getDate(), nCount+1, 0);
```

Comment: *"..I've moved from using: JTables to SWT Tables.."*  .. Why?

Comment: Yes, why would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are just using `Table` (and not the JFace `TableViewer`) you would use:

```
TableItem item = table.getItem(row);

item.setText("text");
```

if you have more than one column use:

```
item.setText(column, "text");
```